# Nasty Age Printing Method

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

I have this ugly age printing method. Can you do better?

```
def age(birth_date)
  today = Date.today
  years = today.year - birth_date.year
  months = today.month - birth_date.month
  (months -1) if today.day < birth_date.day
  if years == 0 && months == 1
    age =  "#{months} month"
  elsif years == 0 && months > 1
    age =  "#{months} months"
  elsif years > 0 && months > 0
    age = years == 1 ? "1 year, #{months} months" : "#{years} years, #{months} months"
  elsif years > 0 && months < 0
    months = months + 12
    years = years - 1
    age = "#{months} months" if years == 0
    age = "1 year, #{months} months" if years == 1
    age = "#{years} years, #{months} months" if years == 1
  end
  age
end
```

Comment: You could consider using `Time.zone.today` or `Date.current` instead of `Date.today` as those methods are time-zone safe

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_(programming_language)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_on_Rails

Comment: @Nakilon: Did you remove the `ruby-on-rails` tag? if that code is what it seems (a helper in a Rails project) it's relevant information, as we can freely use `active_support` (as I do below with `String#pluralize`).

Comment: Ok, you can return it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some notes:

- `(months -1) if today.day < birth_date.day`. Note that this is doing nothing, `months - 1` is evaluated and dropped.
- There is a `age =` in every branch of the conditional, and finally `age` is returned. That's unnecessary and not idiomatic, in Ruby conditionals are expressions, so we don't need to create a variable.
- About this:

  ```
  age = "#{months} months" if years == 0
  age = "1 year, #{months} months" if years == 1
  ```

  It's preferable not to use in-line conditionals when you are dealing with assignments or expressions (it's ok if you are performing side-effects, i.e. `fail("error") if x < 0`). In general follow [functional programming](https://code.google.com/p/tokland/wiki/RubyFunctionalProgramming) guidelines, specially when dealing with logic (if you do some programming that does not deal with logic, please let me know ;-)). It should look (you could also use a `case`) something like this:

  ```
  age = if years == 0
    "#{months} months"
  elsif years == 1
    #{months} months" if years == 1
  ...
  end
  ```

I'd write:

```
def age(birth_date)
  today = Time.zone.today
  total_months = (today.year*12 + today.month) - (birth_date.year*12 + birth_date.month)
  years, months = total_months.divmod(12)
  strings = [[years, "year"], [months, "month"]].map do |value, unit|
    value > 0 ? [value, unit.pluralize(value)].join(" ") : nil
  end
  strings.compact.join(", ")
end
```

Note that, to keep it simple, this code (as yours) ignores the day of the month, which gives a slightly wrong answer.

Comment: Since the question's tagged with Rails, one could just use [`pluralize`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/String.html#method-i-pluralize) instead of the `map` and `case` construct. It'd also make it localizable if that's a concern

Comment: @Flambino: I hadn't seen the Rails tags. But I don't understand what you mean, I can use `pluralize` for the `#{unit}s` part, indeed, but how can it replace the whole map/case block? can you paste the code?

Comment: Actually, I was thinking of just returning an interpolated string, but I'd overlooked the part about about leaving zero values out. So you'll still need an array to `map` and `join`, but I think it can be shortened to `... .map { |value, unit| "#{value} #{unit.pluralize(value)}" unless value.zero? }` which can be then be compacted and joined

Comment: I see. I've edited the code with your suggestion in mind.